# How to replace IIS with Node.js for simple websites

Tags: node.js

I am coming from Microsoft world so please bear with me on this. I was told I could install node.js and use that as a web server instead of IIS. This is a very small business application. In IIS I can create virtual directory and point to the location of the web page and everything works just fine. Based on very little I read, I have few questions;

1. Is it possible to run node js as a windows service or any other form so that it runs for ever? I did find the `forever` package that I think I can use.
2. In IIS, I can create virtual directory set the port and thats it, I have myself a website.

I do not see any examples where I can use a directory where I have a web page, written in java script and point it to run as a web site. All the examples have some thing like server.js and that runs and routes the call. what is the other way to host web sites and use node.js to simple run as a fast web server.

Comment: Node.js isn't a webserver anymore than Java is a webserver. You can write a webserver in Java, and you can write on in Node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was told I could install node.js and use that as a web server instead of IIS.

This is true, but as you already found out then you are in charge of providing for things that IIS was already doing for you (e.g. automatically restart on reboot, or on crashes, hosting multiple sites by creating virtual folders, et cetera.)

You can indeed get all of these things worked out in Node.js and there are several libraries that help on each of these areas. It's not too hard but you'll need to do a bit of researching.

You can also run Node.js behind IIS. Take a look at iisnode http://tomasz.janczuk.org/2011/08/hosting-nodejs-applications-in-iis-on.html

> Is it possible to run node js as a windows service or any other form so 
>   that it runs for ever?

The library Forever takes care of restarting the site when it crashes...but I don't know if you can run it as a Windows Service. I haven't tried that.

> In IIS, I can create virtual directory set the port and thats it, 
>   I have myself a website.

I assume you are talking about a site that serves static HTML files, right? If that's the case that's very easy to support in Node.js either writing your own web server or using Express.js to serve static files.

> I do not see any examples where I can use a directory where I have a web page, 
>   written in java script and point it to run as a web site. All the examples 
>   have some thing like server.js and that runs and routes the call.

Here is an extremely simple example to serve plain HTML files in Node.js https://gist.github.com/2573391 Don't use this in production, though. It's just an example and it does not have any kind of error handling or security.

> what is the other way to host web sites and use node.js to simple run 
>   as a fast web server.

As others have said, you should look into Express.js http://expressjs.com/ It provides some of the infrastructure that you are very likely going to need when building traditional web sites.

Answer (score 1):

You say you're running a "very small business application" behind IIS. Unless it's written for Node.js (in JavaScript), it won't work.

There are no examples pointing to a directory and running that as a website, because that's not how things are done in Node.js. You write a Node.js-application and pull in a webserver-library.

Put simply, In Node.js, you don't embed the appliation in the webserver; you embed the webserver in the application.

Answer (score 0):

When I used node.js, I redirected HTTP requests by a proxy server, nginx. I don’t know if you can directly bind node.js as an HTTP server, but for what’s it worth, nginx is pretty nice!

Answer (score 0):

First things first, allow me to share an introduction. IMHO you should take this decision ( of moving from IIS to nodeJS) by adding various parameters. I belong to the Java & PHP community yet I use NodeJS to achieve extremely specific implementation where NodeJS perform the fastest ( fast IO, AJAX-JSON responses & more ). As you are coming with a Microsoft background you should bare with less comfortable solutions.

Yes, its possible to run NodeJs as a windows service and `Forever` will do fine.

and yes you can create "Virtual Directories" but by creating symbolic links to each of your customer's web site.

I recommend to take a good look at [bouncy](https://github.com/substack/bouncy) & [express](http://expressjs.com/), If you're willing to take this step then these packages is just what you need.

Cheers!